# Value of $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1^n+2^n+\cdots+(n-1)^n}{n^n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I remember that a couple of years ago a friend showed me and some other people the following expression:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1^n+2^n+\cdots+(n-1)^n}{n^n}.$$

As shown below, I can prove that this limit exists by the monotone convergence theorem. I also remember that my friend gave a very dubious "proof" that the value of the limit is $\frac{1}{e-1}$. I cannot remember the details of the proof, but I am fairly certain that it made the common error of treating $n$ as a variable in some places at some times and as a constant in other places at other times. Nevertheless, numerical analysis suggests that the value my friend gave was correct, even if his methods were flawed. My question is then:

**What is the value of this limit and how do we prove it rigorously?**

(Also, for bonus points, **What might my friend's original proof have been and what exactly was his error, if any?**)

I give my convergence proof below in two parts. In both parts, I define the sequence $a_n$ by $a_n=\frac{1^n+2^n+\cdots+(n-1)^n}{n^n}$ for all integers $n\ge 2$. First, I prove that $a_n$ is bounded above by $1$. Second, I prove that $a_n$ is increasing.

*(1) The sequence $a_n$ satisfies $a_n<1$ for all $n\ge 2$.*

Note that $a_n<1$ is equivalent to $1^n+2^n+\cdots+(n-1)^n<n^n$. I prove this second statement by induction. Observe that $1^2=1<4=2^2$. Now suppose that $1^n+2^n+\cdots+(n-1)^n<n^n$ for some integer $n\ge 2$. Then

$$1^{n+1}+2^{n+1}+\cdots+(n-1)^{n+1}+n^{n+1}\le(n-1)(1^n+2^n+\cdots+(n-1)^n)+n^{n+1}<(n-1)n^n+n^{n+1}<(n+1)n^n+n^{n+1}\le n^{n+1}+(n+1)n^n+\binom{n+1}{2}n^{n-1}+\cdots+1=(n+1)^{n+1}.$$

*(2) The sequence $a_n$ is increasing for all $n\ge 2$.*

We must first prove the following preliminary proposition. (I'm not sure if "lemma" is appropriate for this.)

*(2a) For all integers $n\ge 2$ and $2\le k\le n$, $\left(\frac{k-1}{k}\right)^n\le\left(\frac{k}{k+1}\right)^{n+1}$.*

We observe that $k^2-1\le kn$, so upon division by $k(k^2-1)$, we get $\frac{1}{k}\le\frac{n}{k^2-1}$. By [Bernoulli's Inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality), we may find:

$$\frac{k+1}{k}\le 1+\frac{n}{k^2-1}\le\left(1+\frac{1}{k^2-1}\right)^n=\left(\frac{k^2}{k^2-1}\right)^n.$$

A little multiplication and we arrive at $\left(\frac{k-1}{k}\right)^n\le\left(\frac{k}{k+1}\right)^{n+1}$.

We may now first apply this to see that $\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^n\le\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^{n+1}$. Then we suppose that for some integer $2\le k\le n$, we have $\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^n\le\left(\frac{k+1}{n+1}\right)^{n+1}$. Then:

$$\left(\frac{k-1}{n}\right)^n=\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^n\left(\frac{k-1}{k}\right)^n\le\left(\frac{k+1}{n+1}\right)^{n+1}\left(\frac{k}{k+1}\right)^{n+1}=\left(\frac{k}{n+1}\right)^{n+1}.$$

By backwards (finite) induction from $n$, we have that $\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^n\le\left(\frac{k+1}{n+1}\right)^{n+1}$ for all integers $1\le k\le n$, so:

$$a_n=\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^n+\left(\frac{2}{n}\right)^n+\cdots+\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^n\le\left(\frac{2}{n+1}\right)^{n+1}+\left(\frac{3}{n+1}\right)^{n+1}+\cdots+\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^{n+1}<\left(\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^{n+1}+\left(\frac{2}{n+1}\right)^{n+1}+\left(\frac{3}{n+1}\right)^{n+1}+\cdots+\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^{n+1}=a_{n+1}.$$

(In fact, this proves that $a_n$ is strictly increasing.) By the monotone convergence theorem, $a_n$ converges.

I should note that I am not especially well-practiced in proving these sorts of inequalities, so I may have given a significantly more complicated proof than necessary. If this is the case, feel free to explain in a comment or in your answer. I'd love to get a better grip on these inequalities in addition to finding out what the limit is.

Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The limit is $\frac{1}{e-1}$.  I wrote a paper on this sum several years ago and used the Euler-Maclaurin formula to prove the result.  The paper is "[The Euler-Maclaurin Formula and Sums of Powers](http://math.pugetsound.edu/~mspivey/EulerFinal.pdf)," *Mathematics Magazine*, 79 (1): 61-65, 2006. Basically, I use the Euler-Maclaurin formula to swap the sum with the corresponding integral.  Then, after some asymptotic analysis on the error term provided by Euler-Maclaurin we get $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1^n+2^n+\cdots+(n-1)^n}{n^n} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{B_k}{k!},$$ 
where $B_k$ is the $k$th Bernoulli number. The exponential generating function of the Bernoulli numbers then provides the $\frac{1}{e-1}$ result.

I should mention that I made a mistake in the original proof, though!  The correction, as well as the generalization
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1^n+2^n+\cdots+(n+k)^n}{n^n} = \frac{e^{k+1}}{e-1}$$
are contained in a [letter to the editor](http://math.pugetsound.edu/~mspivey/Letter.pdf) (*Mathematics Magazine* 83 (1): 54-55, 2010).

Comment: I think soon the Euler-Maclaurin formula will be renamed to Euler-Maclaurin-Spivey formula. :) +1.

Comment: @Marvis: I have used it in a lot of answers on this site!  And thanks. :)

Comment: Yes. I will never forget http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11726/limit-of-sn-sum-k-1-infty-left1-prod-j-1n-1-left1-fracj

Comment: @Marvis: I think that's probably the best answer I've ever given on this site.  Certainly I spent enough time on it. :)

Answer (score 5):

We can write $a_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(1-\frac{k}{n}\right)^n$. The given limit can then be written in the form
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left[1-\frac{k}{n}\right]_+^n
$$
(where $[x]_+$ is the positive part, i.e., $[x]_+=x$ if $x\geq0$, $0$ otherwise).

I claim that for fixed $k$, $\left[1-\frac{k}{n}\right]_+^n$ is a non-decreasing function of $n$. This means we can pass the limit inside the sum. The limiting value of the $k$-th term is $e^{-k}$, so the value of the limit is
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty e^{-k}=\frac{1}{e-1}
$$

Comment: +1.  Also, this proof appears in Finbarr Holland's follow-up (*Mathematics Magazine* 83 (1): 51-54, 2010) to my paper.  He uses the AM-GM inequality to establish that $\left[1-\frac{k}{n}\right]_+^n$ is a non-decreasing function of $n$.

Comment: Finbarr Holland was my maths. professor when I did engineering. Excellent lectures.

Answer (score 5):

We can prove this by simple squeezing.
Using the fact that $A>B>0$ implies $A^n-B^n \leq n(A-B)A^{n-1}$, and the facts that $e^{-x}\leq\frac{1}{1+x},e^x\geq 1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}$, we have:

$$ e^{-k} - \left(1-\frac{k}{n}\right)^n \leq n\left(e^{-k/n}-1+\frac{k}{n}\right)e^{-k\,\frac{n-1}{n}}\leq e\cdot\frac{k^2 e^{-k}}{n+k}\leq \frac{2e}{n+k},$$

so:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(e^{-k}-\left(1-\frac{k}{n}\right)^n\right)\leq \frac{2e}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{1+k/n}\leq\frac{2e}{n}\int_{1}^{2}\frac{dx}{1+x}<\frac{9}{4n},$$

then:

$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(1-\frac{k}{n}\right)^n=\lim_{n\to+\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}e^{-k} = \frac{e}{e-1}, $$

no need to use any advanced technique.

Comment: I think there's something wrong in $\sum_1^n \frac1 {1+k/n} \le \int_0^1 \frac {dx} {1+x}$

Comment: @HLong: yes, you're right, the integral was intended to be $\int_{1}^{2}\frac{dx}{x+1}$, now fixed.

Comment: No, you can see that $lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n {\frac 1 {(n+k)}} = \int_0^1 \frac {dx} {1+x}=ln2$. So you can't evaluate the series. I think you should evaluate from $e.\frac {k^2.e^{-k}} {n+k}$ because $\sum_{k=1}^\infty k^2e^{-k}$ is convergent